# how to get php multiple result sets object into Extjs store?

Tags: extjs

sql server stored procedure returns multiple result sets into php where I am formatting into a 2 dim array so as to get results returned as single object for extjs store callback.

```
sets[[{"field1": 1, "field2": 2}], [{"field3": 3, "field4": 4}]]
```

Cannot find any examples of how the extjs.store.proxy.reader can handle this. These result sets are not associated so do not think the associated model stuff will help. I can obviously format the php return var anyway, but thought a single array containing the multiple result sets would be a good start. We have single result sets working fine by specifying correct rootProperty in store.

Comment: Why do you need inner array? Without it a store would read it just fine.

Comment: without the inner arrays, the 3 separate result sets from the sql server proc I am calling would be merged into a single result set. No good as each result set eventually goes to a separate store and separate gridpanel. Did work this out - will post solution